# Number of paths from A to B with no direction constraints

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations

There's a fairly common problem finding paths which is usually stated something like this:

> Consider a grid that is 4 rows by 4 columns with the
> upper left corner named A and lower right corner named B.
>
> Suppose that starting at point A you can go one step down or one step to
> the right at each move.  This is continued until the point B is
> reached.  How many different paths from A to B are possible?

This problem is very easy to solve. [One Solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223001206/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/66728.html).

However, this problem becomes extraordinarily more difficult if we ignore the direction constraint:

> you can go one step down or one step to the right at each move.

The only rule is that you cannot pass through the same cell twice.

**Is it possible to determine the number of unique paths from A to B without simply trying every possible path?**

Can we apply our solution to any `n x n` grid? What about any `m x n` grid?

(P.S. This is not a homework question. I came up with it a few hours ago and have been trying to solve it since.)

Comment: Feel free to add any appropriate tags, I'm not sure what category this would fall under.

Comment: @Casteels Wow, great links! Could you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the problem of counting *self-avoiding rook walks*, and for the square case, you can look here for the first few values at the [OEIS here](http://oeis.org/A007764). Unfortunately it seems like there is no known closed-form expression for arbitrary $n$. There's some more information and references at [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingWalk.html).